# Not able to toggle between different div section in html

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to toggle between different div upon clicking the button.

```
<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV')">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV2')">Try it 2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV3')">Try it 3</button>
```

These are Div i want execute

```
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none;">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" style="display:none;">
This is second DIV element.
</div>

<div id="myDIV3" style="display:none;">
This is 3rd DIV element.
</div>
```

Javascript code to  handle the button click and toggle between the div

```
function myFunction(id) {
var divs = ["myDIV","myDIV2","myDIV3","myDIV4","myDIV5"];
for(i = 0; i <  5; i++){
if(divs[i] == id)
    {document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";}
else
    {document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";}
document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = divs[i];
}
```

upon clicking it will always points to the div3, please help. Thankyou.

Comment: how do you call your function ?

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction('myDIV')">Try it</button> , upon clicking this button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use divs[i] instead of the param

```
function myFunction(id) {
    var divs = ["myDIV","myDIV2","myDIV3","myDIV4","myDIV5"];
    for(i = 0; i <  5; i++){
    if(divs[i] == id)
        {document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = "block";}
    else
        {document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = "none";}
    document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = divs[i];
    }
```

Comment: feeling so embarrassed , for finding my silly mistake.